Zod min length of string values in an array created using .transform
Is there a way to check the length of each string within an array after transform?
queries: z
      .string()
      .transform(value => value
          .split(',')
          .map(query => query.trim())
          .filter(query => query.trim() !== ''),
      )
      .pipe(
        z.array(
          z.string()
            .min(2, { message: 'Queries must be at least 2 characters.' }),
        ),
      ),

The currently returns undefined instead of array validation message.
I'm using react-hook-form, maybe it's causing the issue somehow?
When I log the error I also get:
ZodError: [
  {
    "code": "too_small",
    "minimum": 2,
    "type": "string",
    "inclusive": true,
    "exact": false,
    "message": "Queries must be at least 2 characters.",
    "path": [
      "queries",
      3
    ]
  }
]

But the form shows undefined.
Here's my form-message which renders the errors (using shadcn's form).
const FormMessage = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLParagraphElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>
>(({ className, children, ...props }, ref) => {
  const { error, formMessageId } = useFormField();
  const body = error ? String(error?.message) : children;

  if (!body) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <p
      ref={ref}
      id={formMessageId}
      className={cn('text-sm font-medium text-destructive', className)}
      {...props}
    >
      {body}
    </p>
  );
});
FormMessage.displayName = 'FormMessage';

I just noticed that there's a 3 after queries in the path, where is it coming from and why is it in the response? Other fields that are not undefined just have the name of the field, no trailing integers.
"path": [
  "queries",
  3
]


The 3 is part of the array zod validation. The 3rd item on the array that is validated. Its probably because the there strings in your array without the minimum 2 characters. I would suggest filtering out the bad strings right after the split. .split(',').filter(Boolean)
